# What to do with a denounced IP?

Tags: email, spam

I have a VPS and I use it as a personal email and web server. Although there are some other domains hosted on it, the number is less than 5.

From the start, I wasn't able to send emails to Gmail or Outlook accounts, because the IP was on their blacklists (apparently). I had set up SPF, DKIM and rDNS, and every test told me everything is fine, and neither the IP nor the domain was on any spam blacklist, but still unable to send emails successfully.

Some days age, a virus found its way into our server and started to send spams in bulk. I stopped it after 2 days, but it had sent enough spams to get the IP on blacklists. Previously, Gmail used to accept my mails but put them in the spam folder and Outlook rejected them. Now even Gmail rejects them, and everything is so bad.

What can I do to clear up this mess?

The IP address is: 198.23.143.195
The domain: azary.ir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your server is truly clean now you want to go to one of the online lookup sites, such as http://www.dnsbl.info/, then see where you're listed.

For each site that has listed you then you want to get in touch and ask to be removed.

In my experience this is painful, and unlikely to succeed.

Instead your best approach is probably to not send email via that server, do you have outgoing mailservers provided by your hosting company?  If so use that and avoid the problem that way.

Comment: i will contact with seperate DNSBLs, but what can i do with major email providers (gmail, microsoft, yahoo) other than escaping from the problem?

Comment: Major e-mail providers will delist you after a certain amount of time. That time usually depends on how much spam you sent them. I've seen Google delist people after just a few days - others whinge about still being listed months after a compromise.

Comment: this answer is not what I was looking for, but it seems that it is the correct answer. I wish there was a better & more efficient way.